# Blind dialer call Police doesn't work - CALL_PRIVILEGED

Tags: android

I do an application for the blinds (dialer with voice navigation).

When the blind type 190 (Brazil police's) and touch call in my dialer, he cannot make the call!

In the file AndroidManifest is declared CALL_PRIVILEGED permission.

The exception is:

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.contacts / com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity}; Declared this activity you have in your AndroidManifest.xml
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be specifying the Activity you want to use for dialing explicitly, but the Activity is not found on the device. Maybe if you put in an `Intent` which follows the guidelines for making calls using intents?

```
String url = "tel:190";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

This intent should automatically open the device's call Activity.

Comment: Dear Friend, thanks for the response, But, the real problem is: I can not open the default Android dialer! The blind man is lost in the interface, because it does not know where to touch to complete the call. I need to connect directly with ACTION_CALL and this does not happen, even putting CALL_PRIVILEGED. Another problem: Not all devices have a physical button to complete the call.